# How can I find the Sprague-Grundy function of this game?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, pattern-recognition

The game involves N coins and a player can flip any consecutive $K$ sequence of coins, where $K$ is a perfect square.

I have developed a function to list the values, but I am looking for a mathematical way of expressing the SG-value of the coin in the $j$-th position. I have tried, but the values seem arbitrary. How could I find this function? Is it possible?

The first 580 S-G values are as follows:

1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 8 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 2 1 5 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 8 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 6 1 3 1 5 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 4 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 3 1 5 1 1 1 4 1 1 2 1 1 1 5 1 1 2 1 1 8 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 5 9 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 5 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 8 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 3 4 1 1 1 10 1 3 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 4 3 2 1 1 1 5 4 1 1 7 2 1 5 2 1 1 3 1 1 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 4 9 1 1 1 5 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 2 1 1 6 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 7 2 1 2 9 1 1 1 7 6 2 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 11 1 3 1 1 1 2 1 1 6 1 1 2 1 3 4 1 1 2 1 1 1 9 2 1 1 1 5 1 1 1 11 6 1 2 1 4 1 2 3 1 1 5 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 4 1 1 3 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 4 2 4 1 6 12 2 2 1 6 4 1 1 3 1 4 1 9 1 11 2 1 1 1 2 3 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 5 3 1 1 1 5 1 1 1 5 1 1 4 7 1 1 3 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 8 1 1 3 2 1 5 1 1 1 3 5 4 1 1 6 11 4 13 12 13 1 1 1 3 16 1 1 1 2 1

Comment: Also posted on mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311343/how-can-i-find-the-sprague-grundy-function-of-this-game

Comment: I haven't checked very carefully, but I suspect the analysis to be at least as bad as ["subtract a square"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtract_a_square) (which doesn't have a tidy solution), since this coin-turning game is probably very close to an ["octal game"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal_game) where you can subtract a square and then split the remainder into two heaps.